# map api viewport longitude and latitude are off

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a dynamic map API which you can set as you like to. After a person puts in the name of his place I can get the viewport latitude and longitude. First of all, I get 2 values and second they are are both off according to the real coordinates. I see the result back to my own map API as well.

After much confusing I started to compare the 2 and divide them. This still gives a wrong integer. 
With this I get the values which are coupled to the name that has been given.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function(event) {

       var places = searchBox.getPlaces();


       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       var i, place;

       for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          for(key in places) {
               if(places.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                   var value = places[key];
                   var geoLong = value.geometry.viewport.b.b;
                   var geoLat = value.geometry.viewport.f.f;
```

**Example:**

Empire State builiding: Real coordinates: 40.748817, -73.985428.

My results: latitude: 40.746983 and 40.749681 : longitude -73.983858 and -73.986556.

This is from geometry.viewport.b.(b or f) and geometry.viewport.f.(b or f) That's how I retrieved the information.

**Possible solution:**

After much try and error of getting the right results, I stumbled onto this.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
    console.log( "Latitude: "+event.latLng.lat()+" "+", longitude: "+event.latLng.lng() );
});
```

While this is giving the right value back I can't call it like I did with the other 2. It keeps saying that latLng is undefined and that is true because it doesn't work with the objects/array which is given by places.

**Question:** How come that the viewport is giving a different value then the real coordinates?

Comment: 1. don't use undocumented properties (`viewport.b.b`, `viewport.f.f`).  2. why aren't you looking at the point result (`.location`), rather than the bounds of the result (`.viewport`/`.bounds`)?

Comment: If I get the [`.location` for the Empire State Building](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/e7m06zxd/1/), I get 40.748441,-73.985664; where did you get your "real coordinates" from?

Comment: `for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {` this isn't how you're meant to loop over arrays in JS.  Try `for (i = 0, place = places[i]; i < places.length; i++) {`

Comment: @geocodezip I looked at multiple sites and those coordinates were the most common but even then there was a huge variance. About .location it's called just like .viewport. Should I even bother using it because it's just like .viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your intention is to get the position of the place from Google database.

I would suggest following the official API reference documentation and avoid using things like `viewport.b.b` or `viewport.f.f` in your code. Note that once Google updates the version of the API these undocumented properties might change their names.

If you check the documentation you will see that `getPlaces()` method of search box returns an `Array<PlaceResult>` result.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#SearchBox

So, `var value` in your code has type `PlaceResult` that is documented here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult

The `geometry` property of place result has a `PlaceGeometry` type that is documented here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceGeometry

That means that in order to get position of the place you should execute the following code

```
var value = places[key];
var geoLong = value.geometry.location.lng();
var geoLat = value.geometry.location.lat();
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Well I be damned. I tried your option which got commented by geocodezip and didn't work. I heckled with this problem yesterday and today I try out your solution and it works now. Don't know why. Thanks all lot.